# format date in Excel Macro for Certificate from short to long

Tags: excel, vba

i am trying to change the format of  this date: `06/06/2020`

with this format: `06 of June of 2020`;

output excel say the special format is: `[$-180A]d" of "mmmm" of "yyyy;@`

variable `strfechaCurso` read the cell date that i need re-format.

in this macro:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CreateCert()
    Dim shtHoja1 As Worksheet
    Dim strnombreCompleto As String
    Dim stridPersona As String
    Dim stridUser As String
    Dim strClase As String
    Dim strTitulo1 As String
    Dim strTitulo2 As String
    Dim strNivel As String
    Dim strregCurso As String
    Dim strfechaCurso As Date
    Dim strLink As String
    Dim filaInicial As Long
    Dim objPPT As Object
    Dim objPres As Object
    Dim objSld As Object
    Dim objShp As Object
    Set shtHoja1 = Worksheets("PartCurso")
    Set objPPT = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
    objPPT.Visible = True
    Set objPres = objPPT.presentations.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Plantilla.pptx")
    objPres.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Certificados.pptx"
    filaInicial = 2
    Do While shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 1) <> ""
        strnombreCompleto = shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 3)
        stridPersona = shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 4)
        stridUser = shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 5)
        strClase = shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 6)
        strTitulo1 = shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 7)
        strTitulo2 = shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 8)
        strNivel = shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 9)
        strregCurso = shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 12)
        'Need Change the format Here to use on replace'
        strfechaCurso = shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 11)
        strLink = shtHoja1.Cells(filaInicial, 13)
        Set objSld = objPres.slides(1).Duplicate
        For Each objShp In objSld.Shapes
            If objShp.HasTextFrame Then
                If objShp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<nombreCompleto>", strnombreCompleto
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<idPersona>", stridPersona
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<idUser>", stridUser
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<Clase>", strClase
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<Titulo1>", strTitulo1
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<Titulo2>", strTitulo2
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<Nivel>", strNivel
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<regCurso>", strregCurso
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<fechaCurso>", strfechaCurso
                    objShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Replace "<Link>", strLink
                End If
            End If
        Next
        filaInicial = filaInicial + 1
    Loop
    objPres.slides(1).Delete
    objPres.Save
    objPres.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you forgot to explain the problem you are having...

Comment: @braX i dont know how to use `special format` in Macro VBA to convert/re-format the date `strfechaCurso`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fairly straightforward:

```
Sub test()

  Dim dt As Date

  dt = Now

  Debug.Print Format$(dt, "dd of mmmm of yyyy")

End Sub
```

`dd` for the 2 digit date, `mmmm` for the full month name, `yyyy` for the 4 digit year.

Keep in mind that `dt` has to be a `Date` variable and not a `String` variable the looks like a date.

Example:

```
Sub test()

  Dim sDate as String
  Dim dt As Date

  ' this creates a string variable from a date that LOOKS like a date value
  sDate = Format$(Now, "mm/dd/yy")

  ' this will look like a date, but it's not really a date, so you cant use Format
  Debug.Print sDate 

  ' this creates a date variable from the string
  dt = CDate(sDate)

  Debug.Print Format$(dt, "dd of mmmm of yyyy")

End Sub
```

Comment: not work; when i check my power point cert have the same format date.

Comment: Did you try my code all by itself or did you mix it in with all of your other code, not understanding what i'm talking about with it being a string?

Comment: add to your code that instead of debug need replace it with store string date in a variable ...

Comment: Yes, i did not give you exact code you just copy/paste into yours, I gave you example code that demonstrates how to do what you needed to do, so that you could learn from it.

Comment: thank you; i have done it, next tier meet is use the script to replace a square in pptx with Image obtained from a URL API with QR code.